How to specify a reader service PropertyDefinition in a customer Python Processor?
I have created a minimal python example to set a Reader Service Property Definition:
from nifiapi.properties import PropertyDescriptor
from nifiapi.flowfiletransform import FlowFileTransform, FlowFileTransformResult

class PythonReaderServiceExample(FlowFileTransform):
    class Java:
        implements = ['org.apache.nifi.python.processor.FlowFileTransform']

    class ProcessorDetails:
        dependencies = []
        version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
  
        self.RECORD_READER = PropertyDescriptor(
                                name="Record Reader", 
                                description="Specifies the Controller Service to use for parsing incoming data into Records.",
                                required=True,
                                allowable_values=["- create new service -"],
                                controller_service_definition="org.apache.nifi.serialization.RecordReaderFactory")

        self.descriptors = [self.RECORD_READER] 

    def getPropertyDescriptors(self):
        return self.descriptors
 
    def transform(self, context, flowFile):
        return FlowFileTransformResult(relationship = "success")

I see the option to create a new reader service:

When I add a service, I see the following:

My goal is to be able to set the Reader Service and be able to navigate to it, etc., as per this PutAzureCosmosDBRecord example:

What else do I need to include in my Python code?

It seems that just removing the allowable_values property definition was enough to fix this issue.
allowable_values=["- create new service -"],

